# SendMessage with EM_FINDWORDBREAK problem

Tags: c#, api

i try to use SendMessage with EM_FINDWORDBREAK
i have got  the position of mouse >> pos

the problem  is  SendMessage function always  return 0

```
 [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

int  star= SendMessage(hHandle, EM_FINDWORDBREAK, (int)WB_RIGHT, pos);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the import with SetLastError = true and then Marshal.GetLastWin32Error. Also see pinvoke.net if you got the signature right.

Comment: i put this line  Int32 lastError2 = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();  after int  star= SendMessage(hHandle, EM_FINDWORDBREAK, (int)WB_RIGHT, pos);   but also retuen 0

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
 [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
 public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Instead of:

```
 [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
 public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

because the latter only works on 32-bit systems. (Also, the `EntryPoint = "SendMessage"` portion is redundant.)

Comment: More than one way to screw this up, we can't see the constants.  unfortunately the PInvokeStackImbalance warning won't fire on a 64-bit operating system.  Good enough, +1.

Comment: i use win7 32bit    i try this function but same problem, the problem turns out to be difficult after I read the link I originally I wanted to read the text, under mouse but the subject is difficult and I am a newbie to programming ,http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:W2ibceUCnNwJ:www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_24466665.html+EM_GETTEXTEX+c%23&cd=1&hl=ar&ct=clnk&gl=eg&client=firefox-a, sorry for my english